# Core data do not work properly when the application first time loaded

Tags: ios, swift, function, load

I have n ios application, I load and save two arrays when the viewcontroller loads. I save the two arrays exactly the same way but one is not loaded as the other. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (companyEntityIsEmpty()){
        fillCompanyList()
    }

    if (bankEntityIsEmpty()){
        fillBankList()
    }
}
func companyEntityIsEmpty() -> Bool
{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Company> = Company.fetchRequest()
    do {
        self.companies = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if(companies.count == 0){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }

    } catch {
        // handle the error
    }
    return false
}
func fillCompanyList() {

    let listOfCompanies: [String] = ["Burak Akdeniz", "Tonsapp", "Aktif Yazılım"]
    let sortedListOfCompanies = listOfCompanies.sorted()
    var x = 1
    for company in sortedListOfCompanies {
        let companyItem = Company(context: context)
        companyItem.company_name = company
        companyItem.company_id = Int32(x)
        x += 1
        ad.saveContext()
    }
}
func bankEntityIsEmpty() -> Bool
{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Bank> = Bank.fetchRequest()
    do {
        self.banks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if(banks.count == 0){
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }

    } catch {
        // handle the error
    }
    return false
}
func fillBankList() {

    let listOfBanks: [String] = ["Adabank A.Ş.", "Akbank T.A.Ş.", "Aktif Yatırım Bankası A.Ş.", "Alternatifbank A.Ş.", "Anadolubank A.Ş.", "Arap Türk Bankası A.Ş.", "Bank Mellat", "Bank of Tokyo-Mitsubishi UFJ Turkey A.Ş.", "BankPozitif Kredi ve Kalkınma Bankası A.Ş.", "Birleşik Fon Bankası A.Ş.", "Burgan Bank A.Ş.", "Citibank A.Ş.", "Denizbank A.Ş.", "Deutsche Bank A.Ş.", "Diler Yatırım Bankası A.Ş.", "Fibabanka A.Ş.", "Finans Bank A.Ş.", "GSD Yatırım  A.Ş.", "Habib Bank Limited", "HSBC Bank A.Ş.", "ING Bank A.Ş.", "Intesa Sanpaolo S.p.A.", "İller Bankası A.Ş.", "İstanbul Takas ve Saklama Bankası A.Ş.", "JPMorgan Chase Bank N.A.", "Merrill Lynch Yatırım Bank A.Ş.", "Nurol Yatırım Bankası A.Ş.", "Odea Bank A.Ş.", "Pasha Yatırım Bankası A.Ş.", "Rabobank A.Ş.", "Société Générale (SA)", "Standard Chartered Yatırım Bankası Türk A.Ş.", "Şekerbank T.A.Ş.", "Tekstil Bankası A.Ş.", "The Royal Bank of Scotland Plc.", "Turkish Bank A.Ş.", "Turkland Bank A.Ş.", "Türk Ekonomi Bankası A.Ş.", "Türk Eximbank", "Türkiye Cumhuriyeti Ziraat Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye Garanti Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye Halk Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye İş Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye Kalkınma Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye Sınai Kalkınma Bankası A.Ş.", "Türkiye Vakıflar Bankası T.A.O.", "Yapı ve Kredi Bankası A.Ş."]

    let sortedListOfBanks = listOfBanks.sorted()
    var x = 1
    for bank in sortedListOfBanks {
        let bankItem = Bank(context: context)
        bankItem.bank_name = bank
        bankItem.bank_id = Int32(x)
        x += 1
        ad.saveContext()
    }

}
```

As you see the two same functions are being called but only fillBankList() is doing the job when the first time reloaded of application. If I get back to one page and reload the viewcontroller then the function fillCompanyList works. But I need them both work at the beggining of application loaded to the simulator.

Comment: Are all your core data calls in the main thread

Comment: yes they are @NaveenRamanathan

Comment: what does your debugger say?

Comment: I debug all code, it is running into funciton but not saving the data in first load. Its weard becouse the other funciton saves perfectly @RajanMaheshwari